# Powershell rename file

Tags: powershell

I have a question. I have this filename.

210437.rtf

I have this PowerShell code:

```bsh
Dir | rename-item -newname  { $_.Name + "UV arom Fr 150-250°C, 0162-203 cond I"}
```

Which causes the filename to be like this: `2104437.rtfUV arom Fr 150-250°C, 0162-203 cond I`

How can I change it so that it outputs this: `2104371.rtfUV arom Fr 150-250°C, 0162-203 cond I 2104371.rtf`?

Answer (score 2):

Build your string however you like:

`$_.Name` > 210437.rtf

`$_.BaseName` > 210437

`$_.Extension` > .rtf

Be aware that `dir | rename ...` will rename every single item in your current workingdirectory in the way specified. I would recommend to be a bit more specific in the final script.